# What is the difference between "paired" and "unpaired" versions in Wilcoxon's test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, definition, differences

Statistical tests can e.g. be used to decide whether to accept, reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis (the status quo).

There are (apparently) two variants of this Wilcoxon's test: *paired* and *unpaired*. What's the difference between these two?

I would appreciate if you first describe the Wilcoxon's test (maybe with a simple example). In particular, I am interested in the application of this test to assess the difference in performance of statistical models.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test (paired) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test (unpaired) ?

Comment: To get some idea of the distinction between paired and unpaired, try condering $t$-tests:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests